# How to remove multiple versions of python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have multiple python versions on my Ubuntu device. First is Python 2.7.15+, then i have python 3.6.8 and then finally, the one i want, python 3.7.

I can access to 2.7 with **py**
To 3.6 with **python3**
And to 3.7 with **python3.7**

But i want to use only the 3.7 version and access it with py, any way how can I do that?
Also i installed pip and it's using the 2.7 version by default.. That's why i want to uninstall the other two pythons.

Comment: This is better suited for [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Virtual environments are the pythonic way to work with multiple versions. Check [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-python-virtual-environments-on-ubuntu-18-04/) for one option. I used this [virtualenvwrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment#Using_Django_inside_a_Python_virtual_environment) tutorial an find it very useful (don't need to worry that it is part of a Django setup).

Comment: The question is clearly asking to "*use only one version*". Suggesting virtual environments does not solve the "one version" issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen, when playing with python on your OS you gotta be careful since it can break many applications and even the OS itself... anyway :

- 1)Install python3.7 (you've done this already so lets proceed)
- 2)Add Python 3.6 & Python 3.7 to update-alternatives

  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
  /usr/bin/python3.6 1

  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3
  /usr/bin/python3.7 2
- 3)Update Python 3 to point to Python 3.7 with this command

  sudo update-alternatives --config python3

reference to the original guide -

https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-10/

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks. I didn't know it could affect other applications and even OS.

Comment: but with this the user has to do `python3 -m pip install package` for all pip installs instead of just `pip install package`... so surely it is better to have a single clean version ?

Comment: @D.L That's actually not quite true. Users can have two pythons and every one of them just has its own `pip` (there are plenty of guides as to how to install pip for python). Meaning for the OS the 2.7 with its `pip` and for the 3.X `pip3`. If the user doesn't like to use `pip3` he can change the alias to point pip to pip3 but I wouldn't recommend that.. just use `pip3`.

Comment: the user *wants only one version* (in this case 3.7). This is clear. Running legacy versions (and pointing pips to versions) is cumbersome and annoying.

Comment: @D.L But then again the OS is dependent on the python language... you don't mess with the version that comes with OS...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create a symbolic link can just fulfill you needs.

Alternatively, try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your python versions.